# Передача структур в функции внешних файлов

Tags: c

Можно ли передавать структуры в функции внешних файлов?
Не могли бы вы объяснить как передавать структуры в функции внешних файлов?

К примеру при попытке скомпилировать код (gcc -Wall AnotherFile.c -o MainTestProgram.exe) аналогичный приведенному ниже примеру, компилятор ругается на то, что структура не может быть использована за пределами объявления...

Например имеется следующий файл (MainProgram.c) с кодом:

```
#include "AnotherFile.h"
struct product {char name[30]; float price; int amount;} allProduct;
int main() {
   WorkStruct(allProduct);
   return 0;
}
```

Имеется внешний файл (AnotherFile.c) со следующим кодом:

```
void WorkStruct(struct product getStruct) {
   //Какой-то код по работе со структурой
}
```

Заголовочный файл (AnotherFile.h) имеет следующий код:

```
#include "AnotherFile.c"
void WorkStruct(struct product getStruct);
```

Comment: Включение .c-файла в заголовочный, это, конечно, круто. Но неверно. Поместите объявление структуры в заголовочный файл, , туда же *объявление* функции, и включите заголовочный файл в оба .c-файла. В строку компиляции тоже добавьте их оба.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: И лучше передавайте в функции не структуры, а указатели на них